# fullcalendar process checkbox in a modal

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, fullcalendar

I'm using Fullcalendar in a Rails app.  I have a modal for entering data about the event.  One field is an `overtime` boolean.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="overtime" id="overtime" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
```

The following code doesn't work - the calendar doesn't show:

```
select: (start, end, allDay) ->
  title = $("#title")
  description = $("#description")
  hours = $("#hours")
  overtime = $("#overtime")
  workorder = $("#workorder_id")
  actcode = $("#actcode_id")
  $("#dialog-form").dialog
    autoOpen: true
    height: 500
    width: 400
    modal: true
    buttons:
     "Create Labor": ->
       $.create "/events/",
         event:
           workorder_id: workorder.val(),
           actcode_id: actcode.val(),
           title: title.val(),
           description: description.val(),
           hours: hours.val()
           starts_at: "" + start,
           ends_at: "" + end,
           all_day: allDay,
           maxsynch: "N",
           employee_id: $('#calendar').data('employeeid')
           if $("#overtime").attr "checked"
             overtime: "TRUE"
       $(this).dialog "close"
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents')

      Cancel: ->
        $(this).dialog "close"
```

This is the code that doesn't work:

```
$("#overtime").attr "checked"
 overtime: "TRUE"
```

I also tried:

```
overtime: "TRUE" if $("#overtime").attr "checked"
```

If I don't have the test and just use `overtime: "TRUE" - it will set the boolean to true in the db.

I also tried this:

```
overtime: "TRUE" if $("#overtime").checked
```

I don't think it's finding overtime in the html?

The following works in all browsers I've tested EXCEPT IE

```
overtime: "TRUE" if overtime.checked
```

Answer (score 0):

Use True instead:

```
$("#overtime").attr "checked" ->
             overtime: TRUE
```

Comment: `"TRUE"` works for me and `TRUE` doesn't. I tested without the `if` stmt - just force all new ones to be true.

Comment: Don't you have two put a "," before the test?